# spark connector loading vs sstableloader performance

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a spark job that right now pulls data from HDFS and transforms the data into flat files to load into the Cassandra.

The cassandra table is essentially 3 columns but the last two are map collections, so a "complex" data structure.

Right now I use the COPY command and get about 3k rows/sec load but thats extremely slow given that I need to load about 50milllion records.

I see I can convert the CSV file to sstables but I don't see an example involving map collections and/or lists.

Can I use the spark connector to cassandra to load data with map collections and lists and get better performance than just the COPY command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the Spark Cassandra Connector can be much much faster for files already in HDFS. Using spark you'll be able to distributedly grab and write into C*.

Even without Spark using a java based loader like https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader will give you a significant speed improvement.

Comment: yeah, I saw the bulk loader, but I just don't understand how to use it...not a java guy so it hard for me to figure that out...